# How to output the value of the probalbility?

Tags: java

I'm trying to output the probability of winning the craps game.

Every time I try to run the program, the output is empty.

This is the code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class CrapsGame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int diceOne = 0; //declare the following variables as an integer
        int diceTwo = 0;
        int tot = 0;
        int tot2 = 0;
        int point = 0;
        int win = 0;
        int loss = 0;
        double prob;
        Random randomNum = new Random(); // gives randomNum a random value

        for (int counter = 1; counter <= 10000; counter++) { // the loop will run up to 10,000 times
            diceOne = randomNum.nextInt(6) + 1; //gives a random value to the first dice
            diceTwo = randomNum.nextInt(6) + 1; //gives a random value to the first dice    
            tot = diceOne + diceTwo; //calculates the first total

            if (tot == 7 || tot == 11) //if sum equaled 7 or 11
            {
                win = win + 1;
            } else if (tot == 2 || tot == 3 || tot == 12) //if sum equales to 2, 3, or 12
            {
                loss = loss + 1;
            } else
            {
                point = tot;
                do
                {
                    diceOne = randomNum.nextInt(6) + 1; //do loop setting dice1 and 2 equaled to a random number
                    diceTwo = randomNum.nextInt(6) + 1;
                    tot2 = diceOne + diceTwo;

                } while (tot2 != 7 || tot2 != point); //while sum2 is not equal to 7 or point 
                if (tot2 == 7) //if sum2 equal 7
                {
                    loss = loss + 1;
                } else if (tot2 == point) //else if sum2 equal to point
                {
                    win = win + 1;
                }
                prob = win / (win + loss);
                System.out.println(prob);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Empty? I would expect 0 (or 1 if probability is indeed 1). Convert win and/or loss to double before doing the division to obtain a floating-point division rather than an integer division: `(double) win / (double) (win+loss)`.

Comment: You have an infinite loop here `while (tot2 != 7 || tot2 != point)` when `point` is not 7. ... re-think your algorithm.

Comment: is your do while finishing ? are you seeing any exceptions on output like divide by zero, OutofMemoryError etc?

Comment: You may want to debug your code, set breakpoints, check the values of variables, ...

Comment: thank you all for your help, sorry I was away for a moment so I could not immediately respond. I managed to start over and redo the code and it worked! i still have not found the problem